# How to access callback through function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, callback

```
dt.status == 401  || dt.status == 403 ? this._getRefreshToken(()=>{
        console.log("hello");
        localStorage.setItem('auth_token', data.data.auth_token);
       }) : null



export function _getRefreshToken(data, callback){
refreshapi._callAPI( actualurl, 'GET', data, (type, dt) => {
    if(type == 'success'){

        callback(dt);

    }
    else{

    }

});
```

}

when i call _getRefreshToken in that i cannot able to print console, May i know why it is not coming
may be the callback the way i do was wrong?

Comment: I think we need more code to help you better, but are you sure that `type` is equal "success" when status are 401 or 403?

Comment: Yes, I need to know the way callback i do was correct?

Comment: try callback(dt)(); [EDITED]

Comment: no not able to print console

Comment: Can you share more code? or maybe a codesandbox?

Answer (score 1):

```
`export function _getRefreshToken(data, callback){`
```

as per definition callback is second argument but while calling method you are passing callback in first argument. Try with below code

```
`dt.status == 401  || dt.status == 403 ? this._getRefreshToken(null, ()=>{
    console.log("hello");
    localStorage.setItem('auth_token', data.data.auth_token);
   }) : null
```

`